# Stolz angle and uniform boundedness

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $S_1=\{z\in\mathbb{D} \ : \ |1-z|\leq M(1-|z|) \ , \ M>0\}$ be the
> Stolz angle . Denote $z=re^{i\tau}$
> where $|\tau|\leq\pi$ and $0\leq r<1$ . Show that the quantity
> $\displaystyle\frac{|\tau|}{1-r}$ is uniformly bounded in $S_1$ .

A hint says that there is always some $C>0$ for which $|\tau|\leq C(1-r)$ for any $z=re^{i\tau}\in S_1$ . Hence the result will follow . I only got upto the part $$\frac{|\tau|}{1-r}\leq\frac{\pi}{1-|z|}\leq\frac{M\pi}{|1-z|}=\frac{M\pi}{|1-re^{i\tau}|}=\frac{M\pi}{\sqrt{1-2r\cos\tau+r^2}}$$ I don't get why the RHS will be bounded by only a constant factor . Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z=re^{i\tau} \in S_1$ then $|r-z| \le |r-1|+|1-z| \le (M+1)(1-r)$

But $|r-z|=2r|\sin \tau/2|$ so one gets that for $1/2<r <1$ we have $|\tau| /\pi \le |\sin \tau/2| \le (M+1)(1-r)$ so we get $|\tau| \le \pi (M+1)(1-r)$ while for $0 \le r \le 1/2$ obviously $|\tau| \le 2\pi (1-r)$ since $|\tau| \le \pi, 1-r \ge 1/2$, so we are done!

Comment: That application of Jordan's inequality is remarkable !